# Android - OpenGL ES and use of glMapBufferOES / glUnmapBufferOES

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, genymotion

I'm trying to convert my `glGetBufferSubData` calls into *Android OpenGL ES* and i can't find a way to do it. For example, i added this:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES      <---
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
...
```

which supposedly includes the `xOES` functions and therefore `glMapBufferOES` and `glUnmapBufferOES`. Indeed, these functions are found and compiled normally, yet my APK crashes. I then decided to get them by pointers like this:

```
PFNGLMAPBUFFEROESPROC glMapBufferOES = NULL;
PFNGLUNMAPBUFFEROESPROC glUnmapBufferOES = NULL;

...

glMapBufferOES = (PFNGLMAPBUFFEROESPROC) eglGetProcAddress("glMapBufferOES");
glUnmapBufferOES = (PFNGLUNMAPBUFFEROESPROC) eglGetProcAddress("glUnmapBufferOES");

...

if (glMapBufferOES && glUnmapBufferOES) {
   vector<float> v(buffer_size);
   float* mv = (float*)glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
   memcpy(&v[0], &mv[0], buffer_size * sizeof(float));
   glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
}
```

Yet once again my reward is a crash (the `GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES` above is not a typo; in fact `GL_READ_ONLY_OES` is simply absent).
I'm not trying to use `glGetBufferSubDataOES` since there's not a single `GL_x_vertex_buffer_object` extension on my *Android 4.4.4 KitKat*.
I'm using Genymotion. Is there any obvious error on my side or a specific extension to check against `glMapBufferOES` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension you need to check for is [GL_OES_mapbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt). If that shows up in the result of `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`, your device supports the extension.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. In case the extension isn't found as well, is there any other options of retrieving data from a buffer or glMapBuffer and glGetBufferSubData are the only ones ?

Comment: I don't think there's a reasonable way in ES 2.0. You could probably do some crazy rendering that ends up writing the vertex data into the framebuffer, and read that back. It's much easier to simply keep a copy of the data that you store in the VBO, instead of reading it back later.

Comment: This is probably the best approach. The danger of having no-way of peeking the data (etc. no supported extension especially for embedded systems) is worrying :) Thanx